Why is the name Gelfand transcribed as ゲルファント?
I was looking at the Japanese Wikipedia article on the great Soviet mathematician Israel Gelfand and got confused by how his last name is transcribed. I would expect the transcription to be ゲルファンド, but it turns out to be ゲルファント. I though it might've been a historical accident with this particular Gelfand, but found the same thing with other people of the same name. Can anybody explain the origin of this seeming lapse?

Freud is フロイト, Einstein is アインシュタイン.

This is more of a question about other languages than Japanese really, but
In Russian (and also German, not that the two are close relatives), final obstruents are devoiced. In layman's terms, the sounds 't' is performed with your tongue in the same manner as the 'd' sound, except that 'd' involves vibration of the vocal cords. Similar pairs are f and v, p and b, k and g. Because the D ends up at the end of the word, it's devoiced and pronounced as as a 't' sound.

OK, so essentially this is an act of selective tone-deafness on the part of the Japanese? Having Polish as my native tongue, I can confirm that your remark also applies to it. Still, were I to do the transcription, I would've gone with ド.

@WojciechGac Selective tone-deafness?  It seems that the Japanese are trying their best to pronounce his name as a Russian would pronounce it.

"Still, were I to do the transcription, I would've gone with ド" That's because you're accustomed to understanding the sound. The Japanese heard it, exactly because it was not meaningful to them. It's the same as how an art class will have you do exercises to force you to see things as they actually are, rather than taking mental shortcuts based on what you "know" about what they look like. When a voiced consonant gets devoiced, it pretty much by definition is no longer distinguishable from its unvoiced counterpart.

@A.Ellett I'm not saying they're not trying.  Just that there's some amount of phonetic misalignment showing through. I mean the difficulty or impossibility to represent certain phonemes.

@WojciechGac Phonetically, it is perfect aligned. More so than English is. Japanese is purely looking at the pronunciation here. For example "хорошо" in Japanese is ハラショー, as it takes into account the vowel reduction.

@Jimmy More than English - admittedly. Perfectly - I don't think so. The sole fact that Japanese transcriptions (and any words, for that matter) cannot end on a consonant is a serious limitation. In the example you've given the match is pretty good, though the Russian "шо" is way harder than the Japanese "ショー".
